# Django same username in different organizations

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am building an API with Django rest, and I am dealing with a situation where I have to authenticate users with the same username but in different organizations and I have no idea how to do it, any suggestions ?? I would be grateful.

User model :

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=191, blank=True, null=True)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(to=Role,db_column="nom",blank=True)
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    multiple_connections = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
         to=Organizations,on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field="organization_key", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
        verbose_name_plural = "Users"
        unique_together = ('useranme', 'organization',)
```

Comment: You've got a typo in `unique_together = ('useranme', 'organization',)` and 191 characters for a phone number seems a little on the large side :p... Anyway... have you considered using the email address as the login?

Comment: Yeah you are right .. ,for the login, I have to use a username it's the project specification

Comment: Well... it is a username... it just happens to look like an email address? I imagine you'd have to do something such as accepting usernames like `something/org_id` or similar... which from a UX point of view is possibly just confusing... since your email column is unique - that seems the easiest go to that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think of: you'll need to have users specify their organization as one of the parameters for your authentication API endpoint(s), or provide different authentication API endpoints to users from different organizations.

If you go the first route, you might have everyone `POST` to `/my_api/auth/`, and send a payload like:

```
{
    'username': 'Jim123',
    'password': 'password123456!',
    'organization_id': 7
}
```

If you go the second route, you would have multiple endpoints like `/my_api/organization_a/auth/`, `my_api/organization_b/auth/`, etc.

In both cases, you'll have to have your server-side authentication code make sure it's comparing username/password against users in the correct organization (presumably the organization is stored in your database somewhere).

Comment: The issue is not with routes , the issue is with the model instance, i am getting an error because the username is a primary key (A user with that username already exists)

Comment: The precise error message would've been helpful to know from the start. :) If that's your issue, then, and all users are being stored in the same table, you need to make it so the username alone is NOT the primary key. In an ideal world, you'd use a combination of `username` and `organization_id` as a composite primary key, but Django doesn't support that at the database level. So I'd suggest using a standard `id` as the primary key and use [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) with `username` and `organization_id` to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: I updated my question and i added my user model, so with that in place i can create multiple users with the same username ??  how to auhenticate them ??

Comment: So with that model, yes, you can create multiple users with the same username, provided they each belong to a different organization.  As far as how to actually authenticate them goes, that's a much bigger question. I'd recommend reading through [Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/) from the Django documentation as a jumping-off point.